# File(s) encrypter implementation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, aes

I'm looking for any feedback in order to improve code styling, performance etc.
Also I want to make sure that the way I've implemented AES here is actually secure

```
import os
import hashlib
import sys
import base64

from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

class Cryptor:
    def __init__(self, password):
        self.__password = password

    def operate(self, file_):
        if file_.endswith("enc"):
            self.decrypt(file_)
        else:
            self.encrypt(file_)

    def decrypt(self, file_):
        file_name = "".join(file_.split(".")[:-1])

        with open(file_, "rb") as file_:
            save1 = file_.readline()
            save2 = file_.readline()
            save3 = file_.readline()
            salt = save3
            key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac("sha256", bytes(self.__password, encoding="utf-8"), salt, 100000, dklen=32))
            f = Fernet(key)
            decrypted = f.decrypt(save1)
            file_extention = f.decrypt(save2)
            save = decrypted

        with open(file_name + file_extention.decode(encoding="utf-8"), "wb") as file_:
            file_.write(save)

        os.remove(file_name + ".enc")

    def encrypt(self, file_):
        salt = os.urandom(64)
        key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac("sha256", bytes(self.__password, encoding="utf-8"), salt, 100000, dklen=32))
        f = Fernet(key)

        file_name = "".join(file_.split(".")[:-1])
        file_extention = "." + file_.split(".")[-1]

        with open(file_, "rb") as file_:
            file__ = file_.read()
            encrypted = f.encrypt(bytes(file__))
            save1 = encrypted
            save2 = f.encrypt(bytes(file_extention, encoding="utf-8"))
            save3 = salt

        with open(file_name + ".enc", "wb") as file_:
            file_.write(save1)
            file_.write(b"\n")
            file_.write(save2)
            file_.write(b"\n")
            file_.write(save3)

        os.remove(file_name + file_extention)

def main():
    password = sys.argv[1]
    files = sys.argv[2:]
    crypt = Cryptor(password)

    for file_ in files:
        crypt.operate(file_)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Ways of improving:***

*Splitting filename*

Both methods `encrypt` and `decrypt` try to split a filename into *"root"* part and *extension*. 
`encrypt` method makes that even worse and verbose with 2 statements:

```
    file_name = "".join(file_.split(".")[:-1])
    file_extention = "." + file_.split(".")[-1]
```

Instead, that's easily achievable with [`os.path.splittext(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) function (split the pathname path into a pair `(root, ext)`):

```
file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(file_)
```

---

*Generating `Fernet` instance*

Both methods `encrypt` and `decrypt` have the same 2 statements for generating `Fernet` instance (with only difference in `salt` value):

```
key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac("sha256", bytes(self.__password, encoding="utf-8"), salt, 100000, dklen=32))
f = Fernet(key)
```

It's good to extract that common behavior into a separate *internal* function:

```
def _get_fernet_instance(self, salt):
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac("sha256", bytes(self.__password, encoding="utf-8"), 
                                                       salt, 100000, dklen=32))
    return Fernet(key)
```

---

- **`decrypt`** function.
  The variables `save1`, `save2`, `save3` and `save` reassignment are confusing things rather than clarify.
  The variables `save1`, `save2`, `save3` can be renamed to `line1`, `line2` and **`salt`**.
  Aliasing `save = decrypted` gives no benefit - just refer `decrypted` directly.
  Including the above mentioned optimizations the **`decrypt`** method would look as:

  ```
  def decrypt(self, file_):
      file_name, _ = os.path.splitext(file_)

      with open(file_, "rb") as f:
          line1 = f.readline()
          line2 = f.readline()
          salt = f.readline()

          fernet_ = self._get_fernet_instance(salt)
          decrypted = fernet_.decrypt(line1)
          file_ext = fernet_.decrypt(line2)

      with open(file_name + file_ext.decode(encoding="utf-8"), "wb") as f:
          f.write(decrypted)

      os.remove(file_)
  ```
- **`encrypt`** function.
  The variable `file__` in `file__ = file_.read()` does not give an explicit meaning for the *content* being read. Let the content be `content` or `data`.
  The same issues around variables `save1`, `save2`, `save3` and redundant aliases.

  In case if there would be a need to refer the input argument **`file_`** (in both methods) as its original value in different places in methods *body* - you should **not** reassign it in context managers `with open(file_, "rb") as file_:`.

  `os.remove(file_name + file_extention)` is essentially the same as `os.remove(file_)`

  The final optimized **`encrypt`** method would look as:

  ```
  def encrypt(self, file_):
      salt = os.urandom(64)
      fernet_ = self._get_fernet_instance(salt)
      file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(file_)

      with open(file_, "rb") as f:
          content = f.read()
          encrypted_content = fernet_.encrypt(bytes(content))
          encrypted_ext = fernet_.encrypt(bytes(file_ext, encoding="utf-8"))

      with open(f'{file_name}.enc', 'wb') as f:
          f.write(encrypted_content)
          f.write(b"\n")
          f.write(encrypted_ext)
          f.write(b"\n")
          f.write(salt)

      os.remove(file_)
  ```

Comment: Cheers for taking the time and giving a thorough answer!

Comment: @Krishi, welcome, see my last edit for adjusting variable name for Fernet instance